# My program crashes when I try to delete a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

Whenever I try to delete a pointer I get the "windows error noise" and then my program just freezes but never officially crashes.

```
void addIngredient(char ** & ingredients, int & numOfIng)
{
    char * str = nullptr;

    char **tempArr = new char*[numOfIng];
    numOfIng++;

    //init tempArr to nullptr
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfIng; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = nullptr;
    }

    //set the new array to the old array
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfIng - 1; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = new char;
        tempArr[i] = ingredients[i];
    }

    delete [] ingredients;

    //point the old array to the new one 
    ingredients = tempArr;

    //add the new element to the end of the old array
    cout << "What new ingredient would you like to add? ";
    str = new char[25];
    cin >> str;
    ingredients[numOfIng - 1] = str;
    delete str;

    //method tought to us in class on how to clear array and what is being pointers within the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfIng; ++i)
    {
        delete [] tempArr[i]; //Freezes here
    }
    delete [] tempArr;
}
```

I expect the deletion of the elements of the array and then the deletion of the pointer to that array but when I run it I get the standards windows error noise and my program freezes until I ctrl+c the console window. New to coding so please don't flame me too hard. Not sure if it matters but I am using Visual Studio 2017 and debugging in x86.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. How is `ingredients` allocated?

Comment: what about not using pointers? You can use `std::string` for strings and `std::vector` for dynamic arrays

Comment: Please, ask your teacher why they aren't teaching you something like: `void addIngredient(std::vector<std::string> &ingredients) {std::string ingredient; if (std::cin >> ingredient) ingredients.push_back(std::move(ingredient)); }`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry, its initialized as: `char ** ingredients = nullptr;`

Comment: @JasonAdam "_its initialized as: `char ** ingredients = nullptr;`_" If that's the case, `ingredients[i]` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an object (`char`) and then forgetting the new object:

```
tempArr[i] = new char;
tempArr[i] = ingredients[i];
```

What you want to do is set the data instead:

```
tempArr[i] = new char;
*(tempArr[i]) = *(ingredients[i]);
```

This way the new character is not lost.

You also have another issue, when you do `delete [] ingredients;`, you are not deleting the underlying pointers. Then you delete later the temporary subarrays (`delete [] tempArr[i]`), so what you should have done is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfIng; ++i)
{
    delete ingredients[i]; // Note that I remove the [], as you have only new char, not new char[1]
}
```

And no deletion afterwards, as the new `ingredients` is using these "old" `tempArr`.

Also consider using either vectors or unique pointers for your case.

Comment: Given that later in the code we have `delete [] tempArr[i];` I wonder if `tempArr[i]` is a string not a char (and also given that ingredients are normally strings). If so then the OP probably needs something like `tempArr[i] = new char[strlen(ingredients[i]) + 1]; strcpy(tempArr[i], ingredients[i])`

Comment: But the code as a whole is confused, so I don't think this is the only problem.

Comment: @john indeed, lots of confusion, but your comment is valuable and made me realize that OP was deleting his arrays before using them.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher My apologies, `ingredients[i]` and `tempArr[i]` are suppose to be strings. However, after implementing John's suggestion of string copy, I then tried to implement 
`for (int i = 0; i < numOfIng; ++i)
{
    delete [] ingredients[i]; 
}` 
However, this leads to my original issue of it crashing. I changed it to `delete [] ingredients[i];` because I change `tempArr[i] = new char;` to `tempArr[i] = new char[strlen(ingredients[i]) + 1];` Once again, my apologies for not specifying in my original post that `tempArr[i]` is a string.

Comment: @JasonAdam You have to transform `ingredients[numOfIng - 1] = str;` into a string copy too, I guess.

Comment: @Bob__ It still doesn't fix the problem of it crashing when it reaches `for (int i = 0; i < numOfIng; ++i)
 {
  delete [] ingredients[i];
 }`

Comment: You only have one allocation, you can't `delete[]`, you have to `delete`, see my answer!